# MIPS: Offsets with memory addresses for string inputs set or variable?

Tags: memory, mips, offset

Say I have the following to read a string from the user:

```
li $v0,8        
syscall     
add $a0,$v0,$0      
sw $a0,8($s1)
```

If $s1 stores the address at beginning of an allocated chunk of memory, how much does an offset of 8 offset it? Is it 32 bytes or does it depend on what I'm reading? For example maybe if I am reading characters, which are 1 byte each, 8 actually represents 8 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, firstly, you're using the syscall wrong. You can find documentation on the syscalls [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html), but to paraphrase, change it to this:

```
la $a0 buffer #where buffer is the address of a pre-allocated buffer
li $a1 30     #where 30 is the length of said buffer
li $v0 8
syscall #no more than 30 characters now in $a0
```

Secondly, as to your question, the offset is always in bytes.